# How Do I change the version of my Kubernetes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Currently using version `1.11.0` of Kuberenetes.

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.0", GitCommit:"91e7b4fd31fcd3d5f436da26c980becec37ceefe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-06-27T20:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

But Having Trouble changing the version of my Kuberentes to 1.10.5 in Ubuntu.
Any Ideas how to change the my current version of Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves my problem `apt-get install -y kubectl=1.10.5-00`

Comment: run minikube delete first